# Nativescript - Onesignal Push notifications, Android navigation issue

Tags: nativescript, onesignal

I´m having a hard time understanding what am i missing here when the user receives a push notification and then hits the button in order to see it and navigate to the proper page inside the app, so my code is this and by the way it works very well in ios:

So if the application is android, i use this code below... i receive the content and pass it to a function called **handleOpenURL**

```
if (application.android) {
    application.on(application.launchEvent, (args) => {
        try {
            TnsOneSignal.startInit(application.android.context).setNotificationOpenedHandler(new TnsOneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler({
                // notificationOpened: function (result: com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult) {
                notificationOpened: function (result) {
                    const imovelAndroid =  JSON.parse(result.stringify()).notification.payload.additionalData;
                    handleOpenURL(imovelAndroid);
                }
            })).init();
            TnsOneSignal.setInFocusDisplaying(TnsOneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);
            TnsOneSignal.startInit(application.android.context).init();
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error('error', error);
        }
    });
}
```

I´m actually entering the function below, but the problem is when navigating, it simply does not work:

```
function handleOpenURL(argImovel) {

    const precoToNumber = +argImovel['imovel'].preco;
    const precoFormated = Number(precoToNumber).toLocaleString("pt-PT", { minimumFractionDigits: 0 });

      const navigationOptions = {
        moduleName: "detail/detail-page",
        context:{ //my context here which is big so i´m not putting it.
            }
      };
      frameModule.topmost().navigate(navigationOptions);
}
```

Everything works as expected in ios, it is suppose to receive the push, and when the user hits it, the app should navigate to a detail page where the content receive is showned.

What am i missing? thanks for your time, regards.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Manoj, i fixed the issue adding this to my handleOpenURL function:

```
setTimeout(() => {
        frameModule.topmost().navigate(navigationOptions);
    }, 2);
```

Comment: Make sure your Frame is ready for navigation, try logging `frameModule.topmost()` and see if that is a valid frame. May be you could try a timeout of 1 or 2 secs and see whether that fixes the issue.

Comment: Perfect Manoj!!!, that fixed the issue, i set a timeout of 2 seconds.

Comment: By the way Manoj, my push notifications are always appearing on the top of the phone(in android) do you know how could i show this to show the popup style? sorry i don´t know the names exactlly.

Comment: I haven't checked their APIs, but mostly it's just a tray notification on Android unless they allow us to customize the notification received call back. Will let you know when I get time to check it.

Comment: Ok...i will make another question where i will post my code, thanks

Comment: Hi @Japa would you please share iOS version as well, I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your Frame is ready for navigation, try logging `frameModule.topmost()` and see if that is a valid frame.

May be you could try a timeout of 1 or 2 secs and see whether that fixes the issue.